# docker-compose error - unable to read file

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I have a simple docker file for a test django application. I am running docker-compose as root user and I can read the requirements.txt file, but docker is erroring out. Any advice?

```
root@testdeploy:/app/test-project# docker-compose build
db uses an image, skipping
Building web...
Step 0 : FROM python:2.7
 ---> 93d77aec17a0
Step 1 : ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 25e2164606e7
Step 2 : WORKDIR /app/test-project/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 366c21333f1f
Step 3 : RUN pip install -r /app/test-project/requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 75599e289c5e
Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/test-project/requirements.txt'
Service 'web' failed to build: The command [/bin/sh -c pip install -r /app/test-project/requirements.txt] returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Reading the file from command line.

```
root@testdeploy:/app/test-project# head -5 /app/test-project/requirements.txt
Cheetah==2.4.4
Django==1.7
Landscape-Client==14.01
PAM==0.4.2
Pillow==2.6.1
```

My docker file.

```
FROM python:2.7
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /app/test-project/
RUN pip install -r /app/test-project/requirements.txt
ADD . /app/test_project/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docker build executes in a container separate from your host.  The container has its own filesystem and is unaware of files on the host system.

You may copy files to the container by using

`COPY /path/on/host /path/on/container`

in the `Dockerfile`

Currently pip needs files, but they have not been added.

In your case, you can move the `ADD` line at the bottom to before the pip command.  It would also be [better practice to use `COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy), but that is not the bug.

Like this:

```
FROM python:2.7
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
COPY . /app/test_project/
WORKDIR /app/test-project/
RUN pip install -r /app/test-project/requirements.txt
```

If that still doesn't work, you need to adjust `.` to be the correct /path/to/test-project on the host.

Comment: a better way is to copy the requirements.txt first, do the pip install and then copy the rest. that way the pip install will be re-done only if requirements.txt has changer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

One issue to be aware of for future searchers is that the path is relative to the directory of the current `Dockerfile` that `docker-compose` is executing.

This means that if your file is in the same level as your `docker-compose.yml` and your `Dockerfile` is in another directory, you should move it to the directory where the `Dockerfile` is.